# Why does my python code seem to be randomnly selecting words?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

Hi its my first week learning python and I am making a hangman game
I opened a list of words from a .txt file and then going through the words to remove any words that are shorter than 4 or longer than 7 to make an easy list or words.
When i run the code it removes some of the words but not all of them. I don't understand why and can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
easy_hangman_words = hangman_words("easyhangman.txt")  

for x in easy_hangman_words:  
   print(" {} length {} ".format(x, len(x)))

for word in easy_hangman_words:
    if len(word) < 4 or len(word) > 7:
        print(word)
        easy_hangman_words.remove(word)
```

I checked the length of each word before if statement and here is a sample:

represent length 9, 
 Republican length 10, 
 require length 7 ,
 research length 8 ,
 resource length 8 ,
 respond length 7 ,
 response length 8 ,
 responsibility length 14 , 
 rest length 4 ,
 result length 6 ,
 return length 6 ,
 reveal length 6 ,
 rich length 4 ,
 right length 5 ,
 rise length 4 ,
 risk length 4 ,
 road length 4 ,
 rock length 4 ,
 role length 4 ,
 room length 4 ,
 rule length 4 ,
 run length 3 ,
 safe length 4 ,
 same length 4 ,
 save length 4 ,
 say length 3 ,

then printed the words in the if loop and here is what i got

represent

research

response

run

say

it seems to have missed Republican, responsibility, and resource.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're both reading (in the for loop) and modifying (the remove) the list! This can cause python's for loops to get [pretty wonky.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398855/why-does-python-add-newline-characters-to-some-list-elements/56399260#56399260) There are more pythonic ways to do this, but this should fix the traversal problem.

You should try something like this:

```py
remove_words = []
for word in easy_hangman_words:
    if len(word) < 4 or len(word) > 7:
        print(word)
        remove_words.append(word)

for remove in remove_words:
    easy_hangman_words.remove(word)
```

Comment: Well explained, but I feel a better solution would be to fill in a brand new array `allowed_words` :) (Which can be done in-place with a short list comprehension -- but I digress.)

Comment: That worked!  Thank you for your help.  I can kind of see how maybe deleting and reading at the same time could cause problems :)